# How do I assign a value in jquery ui autocomplete based from the database query?

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I'm a currently a student and I studying/trying to make an autocomplete that gets the value and the ID based from the the query returned by the sql query. What I would like to happen is to store the ID of the returned row in a hidden field so that when the form is submitted I can determine the what is the ID of that particular row. I was already able to make the autocomplete textbox work. Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help and very much appreciated.

Here is my code for search.php:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$db = "isproj2"; 

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);


$query = "Select SupplierName, SupplierID from tbl_supplier where SupplierName LIKE '%$text%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['SupplierName'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
?>
```

Here is the code for my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#auto').autocomplete(
            {
                source: "search.php"
                //minLength: 3
            });
        });


    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I would say that you don't need to build your JSON string by yourself. PHP include functions dedicated to theses tasks such as [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php).

Now, if you want to store the value in a hidden field, you first have to give it to the autocomplete using JSON which should be formatted like this:

```
{[
    { "value":"1", "label":"value1" },
    { "value":"2", "label":"value2" },
    { "value":"3", "label":"value3" },
    ...
]}
```

The `label` will be automatically used by jQuery to fill the `autocomplete`.

Then you have to use the `select` event to bind the selected id into your hidden field. It could go like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#auto')..autocomplete(
{
    source: "search.php",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#hidden_field").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

The `ui.item` object represents the selected object.

Comment: Sir, I have a follow up question. What if I have multiple autocomplete textbox paired with multiple hidden fields. How do I do that? Ex. textbox1:name = hiddenfield1: Id.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$return_arr = array();

/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($connection)
{
$fetch = mysql_query("Select SupplierName, SupplierID from tbl_supplier where SupplierName '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) . "%'"); 

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id'] = $row['SupplierID'];
    $row_array['value'] = $row['SupplierName'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
   }
}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($connection);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

jquery:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#hidden_id').val(ui.item.id);
     }
 });
```

Here is a [tutorial that gives a PDO version as well](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Sir, I have a follow up question. What if I have multiple autocomplete textbox paired with multiple hidden fields. How do I do that? Ex. textbox1:name = hiddenfield1: Id.